# Akka router's routees sends Terminate message to itself

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor which creates router. When all work done I want to stop current actor, stop it router and all routees.

This is my code to stop the hierarchy:

```
  // stopping children
  context.children foreach context.stop
  // stopping current actor
  context.stop(self)
```

But in log I'm getting messages like this:

> Message [akka.dispatch.sysmsg.Terminate] from ... to ... was not
>   delivered. [5] dead letters encountered.

i.e. routees sends Terminate message to itslef.

I think the problem is related my code for stopping actors (above).

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stop self, the children are stopped automatically. So just use `context stop self`.

Comment: thank you, but why routees send to itself this messages? When I'm calling `children stop` it means that router itself will be stopped and it automatically will stop it's routees.

Comment: It is an internal message that the actor cannot handle (it is handled by the system) and as it is private, only the Akka system can create one. It creates one when an actor is stopped. You see the dead letters because the children are being stopped twice. Once when you explicitly stop them, and then when their parent is stopped and recursively stops all its children again.